# showing the thumbnails of posts in rows and columns

Tags: wordpress

hello i want to show my thumbnails in a grid-like manner. The markup I am aiming for is this [image]
I am unable to produce the last column, thanks to my poor sense of coding

```
<div class="col">
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/real/bmd.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/real/bn24.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/real/brocode.png" alt=""></div>

            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/real/ck.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/real/etop.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/real/etv.png" alt=""></div>

            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/real/ltw.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="logo"><img src="img/real/mdb.png" alt=""></div>

            </div>
```

But I am unable to produce this markup in wordpress. Here is what I have tried

```
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;

$j= $published_posts/3;
$check =ceil($j);

for ($i=0;$i<$check;$i++)
{
echo '<div class="col">';

if($check>$j)
{   
    $again_check=$i+2;
    if($again_check>$check)
    {
        for ($k=0;$k<3;$k++)    
        {
            echo '<div class="logo"><img src="get_the_post_thumbnail()"> </div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(($j%3)==2)
        {
            echo '<div class="logo"><img src="get_the_post_thumbnail()"></div>';
            echo '<div class="logo"><img src="get_the_post_thumbnail()"></div>';
        }
        else
        {   
            echo '<div class="logo"><img src="get_the_post_thumbnail()"></div>';
        }               
    }
}
else
{
    for ($k=0;$k<3;$k++)    
    {
        echo '<div class="logo"><img src="get_the_post_thumbnail()"></div>';
    }
}   



echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

I need a view where the thumbnails will be shown in 3 rows the number of columns will vary. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can't you just simplify it? Use counter=1. Then $counter % 4 ==0, and then go from there? I'm not sure why you have to put all those conditional statements... Or maybe I'm not understanding your question that clearly on why you need all of those if else and for statements.

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation in my template before. I wanted to make a grid layout without messing up with height stuff..

I came up with this solution

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/4CrU6/

Here, I put counter in for loop. For every 6th element i.e. `ctr % 6 == 0`, I inserted

`<div class="clearfix"></div>` to ensure that the next row elements will be in next row despite of height of the images.. I have demonstrated it in jsfiddle.

Logic skeleton for counter and clearfix

```
echo '<div class="row"> <div class="container">';

for(i=0;i<$check;i++)
{
   //PUT IMAGE MARKUP HERE
     echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></div>';

   if(i % 6 == 0){ //6 is number of elements you want in each row
     echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>'
   }

}
echo '</div> </div>';
```

please refer to the markup I have given in jsfiddle.

Regards,

Rahul Patil.